# print_r($_POST) not working as it should be

Tags: php, logging

I'm trying to create a log file that contains some infotmation, my code is,

```
    $info = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")."    ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."               ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."         ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."          ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n".$_POST."\n";


$req_dump = print_r($info, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);
```

the code logs the information like this,

> 2013-01-15  17:10:15    192.168.0.50              POST         /index.php         http://www.domain.com/article/12
>   Array

the $_POST value is array and no values are being dumped.
How to correct this and get the $_POST values logged?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gotta use `print_r` on the $_POST var, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just appending `$_POST` to your string.  That converts it to the word `"Array"`, because that's how Array -> String conversions work.

You want to `print_r` the `$_POST` array, not the concatenated string.

```
$info = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")."    ".
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."               ".
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."         ".
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."          ".
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n".
    print_r($_POST, true)."\n";

$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $info);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This did the job as I wanted. Thank you eveyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `var_export()`:

```
  $postString = var_export( $_POST, true);  
  $info = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")."" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." ".
                                   $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']." ".
                                   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."".
                                    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n".  
                                    $postString."\n";
```

Comment: Change `$var_export` to `var_export` and I will remove my answer because yours will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$info = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")."    ".
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."               ".
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."         ".
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."          ".
        $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n".
        print_r($_POST, TRUE)."\n";


//$req_dump = print_r($info, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $info);
fclose($fp);
```

You need to do the `print_r` on `$_POST`, not on `$info`.

Answer (score 0):

You place the array from $_POST in a string variable and that's why you get the array.
Try something like this.

```
$info = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s")."    ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."    ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."         ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."          ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\n";
$info .= var_export($_POST) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Try the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php) function. `fwrite` expects only a string as parameter, and you're passing an array

Comment: He is passing a string. The string contains the `$_POST` array, hence `Array` in the string.